# Django export objects to .xlsx file with xlsxwriter

Tags: django, excel, xlsxwriter

I'm using `xlsxwriter` library to export `Django` objects to `.xlsx file`.
It seems to partially work, because I'm getting an issue when the file is downloaded.

I open it with Excel and this issue appears in a window popup :

> An error occurred while sending a command to the program

[image]

Then, if I reopen the file with Excel loaded, it works. So why it doesn't work the first time ?
My excel works fine because I don't have any issue with .xlsx file from internet or somewhere else.

This is my code which let to generate the excel file :

```
def export_categories_xls(request):
    output = io.BytesIO()

    book = xlsxwriter.Workbook(output)
    sheet = book.add_worksheet('Category List')
    row = 0
    sheet.write(row, 0, 'name')

    objects = Category.objects.all()

    row += 1
    for item in objects:
        print(item)
        sheet.write(row, 0, item.name)
        row += 1
    book.close()

    # construct response
    output.seek(0)
    response = HttpResponse(output.read(),
                            content_type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
    response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=test.xlsx"

    return response
```

Thank you ;)